# Convert given string to float without losing precision in java?

Tags: java, floating-point, precision

I want to convert the string to float with out losing it's precision.

```
String str = "140000.01";
float val = Float.valueOf(str);
```

Here, I'm getting the output i.e float value as 140000.02, is there any way to convert it into float without losing precision.

Comment: Use double, double val = Double.parseDouble(str);

Comment: you can also use BigDecimal for getting correct value. `String str = "140000.01";
  
  BigDecimal d = new BigDecimal(str).setScale(2);`

Comment: No, I can't use any other data type other than float.

Comment: @preetk Then you can't get the precision you want. `float` doesn't have it. Make up your mind.

Comment: 140000.01 is between two possible `float` values, 140000 and 140000.015625. 140000.015625 is closer, so it is the correct conversion. The shortest string that would convert to it is "140000.02". To get any closer to your original input you need to use a different data type, not `float`.

Comment: This is a case of There Ain't No Such Thing As A Free Lunch. If you are going to map the entire real line and some NaNs into 4294967296 bit patterns, most numbers you want are not going to be exactly representable.

Answer (score 1):

Simple way you can use `double`, like this:

```
String str = "140000.01";
double val = Double.parseDouble(str);
```

Comment: No I can't use double, i need to convert it into float.

Comment: I think `float` doesn't have it.